# Покрытие всех путей выполнения функции тестами

Tags: c++, c, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ, code-coverage

Есть ли инструменты, с помощью которых можно узнать `path coverage` для тестов? Т.е. процент покрытых путей выполнения кода, а не только процент покрытых строк кода `statement coverage`, который выдает `gconv`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать gcov c аргументом `-b`. В этом случае будет собираться статистика по ветвлениям, например:

```
branch  0 taken 91% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 9%
```

Это не совсем то же самое, что и path coverage, однако можно будет наглядно увидеть, какие ветки остались непокрыты.