# Покрытие всех путей выполнения функции тестами

Tags: c++, c, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ, code-coverage

Есть ли инструменты, с помощью которых можно узнать `path coverage` для тестов? Т.е. процент покрытых путей выполнения кода, а не только процент покрытых строк кода `statement coverage`, который выдает `gconv`.

Comment: интересный баг с вопросами) надо смержить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1399779/495049 с этим